# Return a list where column equals ID several times?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output a list of products based on (prodCategory), please see below for my table structure:

This is my category table structure:

[image]

Then my products table structure:

[image]

As you can see in below image, I have got the categories to output and the first product that is equal to the prodCategory.

[image]

So the question is how do I return all products that match the (prodCategory), my code is as follows:

```
<dl class="accordion">
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE catState = 1";
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                $no=1;
                while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                    $catprod = $row->catID;
                if ($no==200) {
                    echo '';
                    $no = 1;
                }
            ?>
            <dt><span><?php echo $row->catName; ?></span></dt>
            <dd>
            <?php   
                $queryprod = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodCategory = $catprod";
                echo $queryprod;
                $resultprod = $conn->query($queryprod);
                $rowprod = $resultprod->fetch_object();
            ?>
                <ul class="list">
                    <li><?php echo $rowprod->prodName; ?></li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
            <?php
                $no++;
                }
            ?>
        </dl>
```

Comment: You need to learn about `JOIN`.  The query you want is basic SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

obviously you need a basic Knowledge about [JOINS](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx), guess you need this one

```
Select a.prodID,a.prodName from product a JOIN category b
on a.prodCategory=b.catID where b.catState=1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use joins or we can use old method of mysql as:

```
select p.* from product p, category c where p.prodCategory = c.catID and c.catState= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions and answers, I amended my code to the following without using JOIN but using JOIN is a great way when using several tables and something I need to look into more.

```
<?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE catState = 1";
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                $no=1;
                while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                    $catprod = $row->catID;
                if ($no==200) {
                    echo '';
                    $no = 1;
                }
            ?>
            <dt><span><?php echo $row->catName; ?><?php echo $catprod; ?></span></dt>
            <dd>
            <?php 
                $queryprod = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodCategory = $catprod";
                $resultprod = $conn->query($queryprod);

                while($rowprod = $resultprod->fetch_object()){
                echo '<ul class="list">
                    <li>' . $rowprod->prodName . '</li>
                </ul>';
                }
                $resultprod->free();
            ?>
            </dd>
            <?php
                $no++;
                }
            ?>
```